# wireless network with cable modem and access point

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-access-point, cable-modem

I have a Scientific Atlanta EPC2203 cable modem and a TP-Link TL-WA500G access point. When I connect my computer directly to modem with a CAT5e cable I have internet connection on my laptop (when i type ipconfig i see my external ip there, provided by isp).

So I decided to have wireless network in the flat, allowing other devices to connect as well. I bought this wireless ap (TL-WA500G) configured Wireless security stuff, and connected it to my modem. With that configuration (by default AP has static ip of 192.168.1.254) only my computer can connect to internet over wifi, but not any other device. When I set the IP of AP to Dynamic IP (DHCP) it is the same.

How should I change my configuration to enable all wifi devices to connect to internet?

Comment: You need to set-up a Wi-Fi network on the AP if it supports it. In doing so, you give it a broadcast SSID name, security mode(s) like WPA, wireless mode(s) like 802.11a/b/g/n, PSK, etc.

Comment: i already did it, devices see the SSID when they scan for wifi but they cannot connect to internet (it hangs forever on obtaining IP address)

Comment: You may have a physical problem with the router. Did you enable MAC address restrictions? Can these other computers connect fine when wired to the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share the single Internet connection with multiple computers you need a [router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) not an [access point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point).

> The most familiar type of routers are home and small office routers
>   that simply pass data, such as web pages and email, between the home
>   computers and the owner's cable or DSL modem, which connects to the
>   Internet through an ISP.